# Using A 4 Ohm Speaker With Arduino

Tags: programming, c++, sketch

I've salvaged a 4 Ohm, 1.5 Watt speaker from an old computer, and I was wondering how I'd go about getting it to work with my Arduino. I've heard of various amplifier circuits such as opamps, but I do not know which would be the best for my situation. I've also heard that using the speaker in certain ways (such as directly connected to a pin from the Arduino) could damage both the speaker and the output pin, so that is definitely something I'd like to avoid. I'm not looking for anything complicated; I'm just trying to get a feel for the general circuitry, programming, and speaker volume. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5v, 4ohm, >1amp from a pin rated for 0.04amps; this isn't safe!
You would need a driver, but it would suffice to add a small transistor & a couple of resistors to drive it; [here](http://hackaweek.com/hacks/?p=327) is a slightly more complex layout, there are many examples on the web.